# Deserialize flatbuffers binary that represents non-root table

Tags: c++, deserialization, flatbuffers

Is it possible to deserialize a binary flatbuffers object that represents a non-root table?

Suppose the following flatbuffers schema:

```
table Foo {
    ...
}
table Bar {
    value:[Foo];
}
root_type Bar;
```

Suppose we have access to the binary data that represents the `Foo` object. Is it possible to deserialize this binary to an object of class `Foo`? Looking at my c++ generated header file, I do not see any generated function like `GetFoo()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetFoo` is just a convenience function for the declared `root_type` that calls `GetRoot<Foo>`, you can use `GetRoot<Bar>` to access any type as the root, assuming the buffer was constructed as such.

Comment: Oh, this is embarrassing. Thank you so much. Your answer prompted me to look at the documentation once again and find this comment right in the tutorial: "`GetMonster` is a convenience function that calls `GetRoot<Monster>`, the latter is also available for non-root types."